# Phalconphp routing for multimodule application

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I've created a multimodule application using phalconphp developer tool:

```
phalcon project <projectname> module
```

And I've added a backend module (the frontend is generated). Now I would like all backend routing do the following:

```
$route->add('/admin/:controller/:action/:param', array(
    'module' => 'backend',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3,
));
```

But my routing also defines:

```
$router->setDefaultModule("frontend");
$router->setDefaultNamespace("Groendesign\Backend\Controllers");
```

And therefor when I browse to: `http://myprojectname/admin` it searches in my backend module for the frontend Namespaces, How should I proceed with this?

What I want to achieve is that every url that has the prefix /admin/ is send to the backend module. Using the url to define which controller, action and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by removing the setDefaultNamespace from my bootstrap and adding it to the Modules.php file in each Module. Thereby setting the DefaultNamespace only in the correct module.